# Function started with std::async crashes after quite a few iterations

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, asynchronous

I am trying to develop a simple evolution algorithm in C++. To make my calculations faster I decided to use async functions to run multiple calculations at once:

```
std::vector<std::future<int> > compute(8);
unsigned nptr = 0;
int syncp = 0;
  while(nptr != network::networks.size()){
    compute.at(syncp) = std::async(&network::analyse, &network::networks.at(nptr), data, width, height, sw, dFnum.at(idx));
    syncp++;
    if(syncp == 8){
      syncp = 0;
      for(unsigned i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        compute.at(i).get();
      }
    }
    nptr++;
  }
```

This is how I start my calculating function. The function is called `analyse`, and for each "network" it assigns a score depending on how good it identifies the image.

This is part of the analyse function:

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < entry.size(); i++){
    double sum = 0;
    data * d = &entry.at(i);
    pattern * p = &pattern::patterns.at(d->patNo);
    int sx = iWidth;
    int sy = iHeight;
    if(d->xPercentage*iWidth + d->xSpan*iWidth < sx) sx = d->xPercentage*iWidth + d->xSpan*iWidth;
    if(d->yPercentage*iHeight + d->xSpan*iWidth < sy) sy = d->yPercentage*iHeight + d->xSpan*iWidth;
    int xdisp = sx-d->xPercentage*iWidth;
    int ydisp = sy-d->yPercentage*iHeight;
    for(int x = d->xPercentage*iWidth; x < sx; x++){
      for(int y = d->yPercentage*iHeight; y < sy; y++){
        double xpl = x-d->xPercentage*iWidth;
        double ypl = y-d->yPercentage*iHeight;
        xpl /= xdisp;
        ypl /= ydisp;
        unsigned idx = (unsigned)(xpl*(p->width) + ypl*(p->height)*(p->width));
        if(idx >= p->lweight.size()) idx = p->lweight.size()-1;

        double weight = p->lweight.at(idx) - 5;

        if(imageData[y*iWidth+x])
          sum += weight;
        else
          sum -= 2*weight;
      }
    }
    digitWeight[d->digit-1] += sum;
  }
}
```

Now, there is no need to analyse the function itself - I'm sure it works, I have tested it on a single thread, and it runs just fine. The only problem is, after some time of execution, I get errors like segmentation fault, or vector range check error.

They mostly happen at this line:

```
    digitWeight[d->digit-1] += sum;
```

Now, you can be sure that `d->digit-1` is a valid range for this array.
The problem is that the value of the `d` pointer is different than it was here:

```
        data * d = &entry.at(i);
```

It magically changes during the execution of the function, and starts pointing to different data, leading to errors. I have tried saving the value of `d->digit` to some variable and later use this variable, and it worked fine for just a while longer, before crashing on another shared resource, `imageData` this time.

I'm thinking this might be something related to data sharing - all async functions share the same array of data - it's a static vector. But this data is only read, not written anywhere, so why would it stop working? I know of something called mutex locking, but this would make no sense to lock this async functions, as it would run just as slow as a single threaded program would run.

I have also tried running the functions like this:

```
  std::vector<std::thread*> threads(8);
  unsigned nptr = 0;
  int threadp = 0;
  while(nptr != network::networks.size()){
    threads.at(threadp) = new std::thread(&network::analyse, &network::networks.at(nptr), data, width, height, sw, dFnum.at(idx));
    threadp++;
    if(threadp == 8){
      threadp = 0;
      for(unsigned i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if(threads.at(i)->joinable()) threads.at(i)->join();
        delete threads.at(i);
      }
    }
    nptr++;
  }
```

and it did work for a second, but after some time a very similar error appeared.
Data is a structure containing 7 integers, one of which is an ID of
pattern, and pattern is a class that contains two integers - width and height
and vector of chars.

Why does it happen on read-only data and how can I prevent it?

Here is an example of what happens:
[image]

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, including the declarations and initializations of all arrays, vectors and pointers (so we know their sizes at least).

Comment: Also please run in a debugger to catch the crash when it happens, and so you can locate where in your code it happens (and also check the values of all variables at the point of the crash). Also update your question with those details.

Comment: What is `digitWeight`? How is it created and/or initialized? What is the value of `d->digit`? Is `d->digit - 1` in range of `digitWeight`? Is `digitWeight[d->digit - 1]` initialized?

Comment: @Karol [Please take a moment to familiarise yourself with the post markup language.](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) In particular, you don’t need to (and shouldn’t) use `<br>` line breaks to create paragraphs. Just separate your paragraphs by an empty line.

Comment: Is any of the data you use shared between threads by the way? Then you need to protect that data from data-races.